# Why is inflate tool not working

Tags: sculpt

I ham having an issue on the donut tutorial for the part where you apply inflate tool to the drips on the icing of the donut and it makes it more inflated. For me it was just “lifting” up the drips, and not inflating. I have seen the exact same issue as this one and the solution was to make sure solidify was on but that did not work for me. I am grateful for any help.
My file is at https://blend-exchange.com/b/Nssrv7Zx/

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: If the file is too big (>20 MB) you also can share the file via google/one drive, dropbox, wetransfer.com, or any other file hosting service and post the link here.

Comment: I have now edited my post to have the donut in it if you want to check that out

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I added the solidify modifier to the list but I didn’t know you had to click “apply” for it to actually work.